# QuickTime not looping wav file correctly

Tags: quicktime

I am trying to play a wav file on a loop in QuickTime 7.6.4 on Windows.  The wav file plays correctly the first time through but plays only a snippet of the file on subsequent loops.  The sound is like an alarm clock.  The second and all subsequent times through it appears to play only the last tone of the sound.

Windows Media Player can loop the file and it plays correctly on each loop.  I want it to play correctly in QT because this is a background sound I want to play on  web page in IE, safari, and firefox.  Firefox and Safari both are using QT.

You can find the file beep.wav at https://sites.google.com/site/busyspin/files

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out.  It turns out that QuickTime does some buffering at the beginning of a loop that causes the beginning of the file not to be played after the first time through.  Here is a link to an apple mailing list post about this issue.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/QuickTime-API/2007/Sep/msg00184.html